# Sql query to get row from date filled

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I want to get data from training_course table where current date minus 5 days is equal to training_end_date. Training_end_date is my field in the table.
Thanks

Comment: You should try to resolve it on your onw by ussing google or any other tools available on the internet and then ask for doubts on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select * 
from training_course 
where training_end_date = current_date - interval 5 day
```

Or, if your dates have time components, you *maybe* want:

```
select * 
from training_course 
where training_end_date >= current_date - interval 5 day and training_date < current_date - interval 4 day
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works with the first one as I only need the day.